# Net Core not connecting to mysql on linux production

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, .net-core, digital-ocean, ubuntu-19.04

I followed this blog's tutorial on hosting Net Core Web App to Linux Ubuntu 19,

> https://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNETCoreWebsiteToACheapLinuxVMHost.aspx

but after hosting, I have mysql database running on the same server, but my web fails to load any data. Any help as to how I should Change my ConnectionString?

> "MySQLConnection": "Server=127.0.0.1;Database=database_name;User=user_name;Password=password_correct;CharSet=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;SslMode=none;"
>
> "MySQLConnection": "Server=127.0.0.1:8080;Database=database_name;User=user_name;Password=password_correct;CharSet=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;SslMode=none;"

Here is my startup code:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(
    options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySQLConnection"), 
                mySqlOptions =>
                {
                    mySqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(5, 7, 24), ServerType.MySql);
                    mySqlOptions.DisableBackslashEscaping();
                }
));
```

It runs well, but won't connect to database. Kindly assist.

Getting error:

> MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs, line 326

```
MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, 
ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs
MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs
MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(Nullable<IOBehavior> ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable<IOBehavior> ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(bool errorsExpected)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(bool errorsExpected)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable<T>+Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, bool buffer)
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.Execute<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, TResult> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, ExecutionResult<TResult>> verifySucceeded)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable<T>+Enumerator.MoveNext()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider._TrackEntities<TOut, TIn>(IEnumerable<TOut> results, QueryContext queryContext, IList<EntityTrackingInfo> entityTrackingInfos, IList<Func<TIn, object>> entityAccessors)+MoveNext()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider+ExceptionInterceptor<T>+EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.GetListItemsWithValueField()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.GetListItems()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.GetEnumerator()
System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.DefaultHtmlGenerator.GenerateGroupsAndOptions(string optionLabel, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, ICollection<string> currentValues)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.DefaultHtmlGenerator.GenerateSelect(ViewContext viewContext, ModelExplorer modelExplorer, string optionLabel, string expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, ICollection<string> currentValues, bool allowMultiple, object htmlAttributes)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.SelectTagHelper.Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.RunAsync(TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext)
AspNetCore.Views_Appointments_BookAppointment.<ExecuteAsync>b__20_0() in C:\Users\User\source\repos\TPSolution\src\WebApplication\Frescar\Views\Appointments\BookAppointment.cshtml
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.GetChildContentAsync(bool useCachedResult, HtmlEncoder encoder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.RenderAtEndOfFormTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.RunAsync(TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext)
```

**Note: It works well on when developing with the Visual Studio, locally on my Windows 10 while testing with IIS.**

Comment: Is the MySql database on the VM being hosted at 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes it is in the same VM, but apache is running on port 8080

Comment: This is what I am getting 

MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in ServerSession.cs, line 326

Comment: @GithithuWambura you didn't post the error message, only the line where it occured. Post the error message at least. The full exception text would be even better as it includes any inner exceptions and the call stack that shows which calls led to the exception

Comment: @Kanavos I have updated some of the error.

Comment: Same issue, any updates? Thanks!